# SSL on domain but not phpmyadmin

Tags: ssl, phpmyadmin

*SSL* on domain, but not on *PHPMYADMIN*, causing site (with SSL) to become untrusted.
On digitalocean, ubuntu with apache.
website is namedream dot com

The website is namedream.com if you search for a word like "cool" you will see the issue.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
```

Do on namedream.com/index.php the SSL works fine.

But when I search for a word, say "cool", I get this error in Chrome:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directoryDatabase access
>   failed: It always worked before not sure what's happening here.